# Filtering in mlr3filters - where can I find details about the methods?

Tags: r, mlr3

I try to find details about the filtering methods that are mentioned here:

https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/list-filters.html#list-filters

https://mlr3filters.mlr-org.com/

Unfortunately, I could not find more detailed information, e.g. how is `information_gain` calculated and what parameter can I set.

Where do I find details about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at the [function references](https://mlr3filters.mlr-org.com/reference/index.html) and check the underlying R functions which are wrapped by {mlr3filters} and their respective help pages.