# AUC filter in ml3filters

Tags: feature-selection, auc, mlr3

I try to understand more about the AUC filter of mlr3filters. I use a classification task (`task`) and the following code:

```
filter = flt("auc")

filter$calculate(task)

result<-as.data.table(filter)
```

From the documentation in mlr3measures::auc(), I understand that I need a vector of probabilities and a vector with (binary) factor values as well as the "true" class. In my task, I have the binary class (as "target") and many features which are numeric, but *not* between 0 and 1, so I cannot interpret them as a probability.
Why is AUC calculated then? Or is there an additional assumption? My problem is that I cannot read this from `filter$help()`.

As a general question: Is there an additional "explanation layer" between the function references in https://mlr3filters.mlr-org.com/reference/index.html and the underlying R functions? For example, I understand that FilterVariance$new() generates a filter object that calculates the variances of the single features by *only using these features* and applying stats::var(). But from the book, I also see that I can specify cutoff values:

`po("filter", mlr3filters::FilterVariance$new(), filter.frac = 0.5)`

Where do I find details about this filter.frac value? I cannot find it in `filter$help()` and also not in stats::var()

Similarly, I understand that FilterCorrelation$new() generates a filter object that takes the single features *and the target* to calculate the feature ranks. This may be self-explanatory, but I wonder where I could find more details about such issues.

I tried the answer that I found here ([Filtering in mlr3filters - where can I find details about the methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66699110/filtering-in-mlr3filters-where-can-i-find-details-about-the-methods)) , but I could not find details in `filter$help()`

Thanks in advance for beginners$help()

Comment: check out the source, it should be clear: https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3filters/blob/main/R/FilterAUC.R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the documentation of the AUC filter states that it is analogous to `mlr3measures::auc`, it does not actually use that function. Instead, it uses its [own implementation](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3filters/blob/37413f1868c9781e827e02fbbfe609cb20f38792/R/FilterAUC.R#L55-L63) which calculates the [**A**rea **U**nder the ("Receiver Operating Characteristic") **C**urve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Area_under_the_curve), which does not require a probability value, only a continuous value that can be used to divide samples with a cutoff.

The `Filter`s, as I understand them, are primarily used to calculate filter scores (see the [documentation of the `Filter` base class](https://mlr3filters.mlr-org.com/reference/Filter.html)). They are mostly useful in combination with the `PipeOpFilter` from the [`mlr3pipelines`](https://mlr3pipelines.mlr-org.com/index.html) package, which is also what the example from the [book](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/pipe-modeling.html) that you cite is doing. `PipeOp`s are generally useful to integrate a filtering step (or any kind of preprocessing) into a learning process (the [book chapter on `mlr3pipelines`](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/pipelines.html) is probably a good point to learn about that). However, these can also be used to compute steps, e.g. filter out columns from a `Task`:

```r
pof = po("filter", mlr3filters::FilterVariance$new(), filter.frac = 0.5)
task = tsk("iris")
pof_result = pof$train(list(task))
pof_result[[1]]
#> <TaskClassif:iris> (150 x 3)
#> * Target: Species
#> * Properties: multiclass
#> * Features (2):
#>   - dbl (2): Petal.Length, Sepal.Length
pof_result[[1]]$data()
#>        Species Petal.Length Sepal.Length
#>   1:    setosa          1.4          5.1
#>   2:    setosa          1.4          4.9
#>   3:    setosa          1.3          4.7
#>   4:    setosa          1.5          4.6
#>   5:    setosa          1.4          5.0
#>  ---                                    
#> 146: virginica          5.2          6.7
#> 147: virginica          5.0          6.3
#> 148: virginica          5.2          6.5
#> 149: virginica          5.4          6.2
#> 150: virginica          5.1          5.9
```

See [`?PipeOp`](https://mlr3pipelines.mlr-org.com/reference/PipeOp.html) about the `$train()` method (although really the book chapter is a better place to start imho). The [`?PipeOpFilter`](https://mlr3pipelines.mlr-org.com//reference/mlr_pipeops_filter.html) documents the `filter.frac` hyperparameter:

> ```
> Parameters:
>
> [...]
>
>    • ‘filter.nfeat’ :: ‘numeric(1)’
>      Number of features to select. Mutually exclusive with ‘frac’
>      and ‘cutoff’.
>
>    • ‘filter.frac’ :: ‘numeric(1)’
>      Fraction of features to keep. Mutually exclusive with ‘nfeat’
>      and ‘cutoff’.
>
>    • ‘filter.cutoff’ :: ‘numeric(1)’
>      Minimum value of filter heuristic for which to keep features.
>      Mutually exclusive with ‘nfeat’ and ‘frac’.
>
> Note that at least one of ‘filter.nfeat’, ‘filter.frac’, or
> ‘filter.cutoff’ must be given.
> ```

So what it is doing is to run the `Filter`'s `$calculate()` function and select features based on the resulting `$score`.

To answer the more general question on where to get help: Usually the object classes (which you can usually find out by calling `class(object)`) are a good first start to look at; often these classes inherit from more general base classes that also explain some parts of the process if they are not familiar. In this example the [`PipeOpFilter`](https://mlr3pipelines.mlr-org.com//reference/mlr_pipeops_filter.html) inherits from several classes, among them [`PipeOp`](https://mlr3pipelines.mlr-org.com/reference/PipeOp.html) -- this is stated in the help file. Besides that, there is the book, which you know about. Finally, if everything else fails, it may become necessary to look at the source code, unfortunately.